# inside a javascript for each loop, why does the first element behave differently than the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dynamic

I'm trying to dynamically create 3 "furniture cards" on body load where each card implements the [jQuery resizeable plugin](https://jqueryui.com/resizable/#constrain-area), but only the first item seems to be resizable within its container (both width and height). The other two are **only** resizable in height.

Not sure if it's my code or if I'm mishandling the plug-in or if it's something even more complicated than that. Would appreciate help, thanks in advance.

script.js

```
$(function() {
    $(".r").resizable({
        containment: '.card'
    });
});

//array of furniture items
furnitureCaption = ['chair', 'plant', 'table'];

//dynamically create furniture cards on load
function init() {

    //get the element we are appending to
    var container = document.querySelector('.container');

    furnitureCaption.forEach((cap, i) => {
        //create the element we are appending
        var card = document.createElement('div');
        card.className = "ui-widget-content card";

        var cardDetail = document.createElement('div');
        cardDetail.className = "ui-state-active r";

        //set the background image based on picture url  array
        cardDetail.style.backgroundImage = "URL(./img/" + cap + ".png)";
        cardDetail.style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";

        //make the span caption based on caption array
        var spanTag = document.createElement('span');
        spanTag.innerHTML = furnitureCaption[i];

        //append and put on page
        cardDetail.append(spanTag);
        card.append(cardDetail);
        container.append(card);
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<body onload="init()">
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

style.css

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 4em;
}

.card {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}

.card h3 {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.r {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 20px;
    min-height: 20px;
}

.r,
.card {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

span {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: `$(".r").resizable();` only initializes the widget on the elements that exist at that time. New elements added after that don't have the widget added.

Comment: When you create new elements in the loop, you need to configure the widget on each one.

Comment: hmmm, i tried to put $(".r").resizable() inside my init() method so that it would run at the same time as the script but it doesn't seem to work? or should i be "styling" (since it's a css class) the widget when its being made? @Barmar

Comment: Use `$(cardDetail).resizeable()`